# How to use a macro with 2 variables

Tags: c

Can someone help me understand the below macro?

`#define variable_1 tF32 const variable_2 = variable_3`

The variable_3 is actually a parameter which can be changed, I don't understand how it can affect after a software is built.

Comment: It replaces `variable_1` with `tF32 const variable_2 = variable_3`.

Comment: Because `variable_1` gets replaced with `tF32 const variable_2 = variable_3`, this means that the line `variable_1;` will get replaced with `tF32 const variable_2 = variable_3;`.

Comment: Hint: don't use macros like this. They make your your code less readable and more error prone.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor works during the compilation process, before the actual compilation of the code. It performs textual substitution based on the defined macros. Whenever the preprocessor encounters the token `variable_1` in the code, it will replace it with `tF32 const variable_2 = variable_3`. The value of `variable_3` will be used at the time of substitution.

Once the code is compiled and the executable is generated, the macro definitions are no longer relevant. Therefore, any changes made to `variable_3` after the software is built will not affect the already compiled executable. The purpose of using such macros is to define commonly used code patterns and provide configuration options at compile-time. The value of `variable_3` is determined at the time of the substitution, based on the context in which the macro is used.